# Select multiple values in a dropdown in angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-forms

I would like to select multiple values in a dropdown. But the dropdown options are asynchronously fetched through REST API. I tried with `<select multiple> with ngFor Directive`, but it didn't work.

Comment: share code please

Comment: You can have a look at angular material select, it supports multiple selections as well: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can always use check boxes in the drop-down list and create a custom directive that check if check box is selected then it triggers some CSS highlight style and furthermore if you don't want to show check-box set its visibility to invisible so it works but only under the hood
(Just an idea)
There would be some extra work like if the drop down goes out of focus you would want the check-boxes to be deselected again so you would also have to check for that in the directive.